# Why regex behave differently from string in Angular Form Validator

Tags: angular

This validator for my form control behaves differently based on the declaration (even thou the method interface can accept RegExp or string). For example, when I paste username in the input and then paste white space, the first example of the pattern does not validate the error, unlike the second one.

[image: Regex]
[image: String regex]

Comment: Post code as text, not as images.

Comment: Post aswell the type RegExp and the issue should reveal itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunataly not documented, but when you pass a string, Angular adds `^` at the beginning (if not present yet) and `$` at the end (if not present yet). If you pass a Regexp, it uses it as is.

See the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.1.2/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L272-L322).

Comment: I've created a PR to clarify the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27560

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation should include an example where a regex is passed as the pattern.

The following email pattern fails...

```
Validators.pattern('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$')
```

However passing the regex works as expected...

```
Validators.pattern(/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/)
```